# Usage of AJAX in an alert box

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

I have a javascript alert asking the user to insert a password. When user presses button, I will do an AJAX call to check the password. This could generate another alert with the response (if it was accepted or not), but I wonder if it is possible to have the AJAX response change the text of my first alert? Is it even possible to override the alert button's default not to close itself when clicking "okay"?

Comment: please show some code.

Comment: No. Use jquery ui modal dialog

Comment: The alert produced by the standard `window.alert()` function only allows the message text to be changed - you can't change the button text or behaviour. You can implement an html/css modal dialog (easy with jQuery plugins, but really not particularly difficult even with vanilla JS).

Comment: Could you be talking about a [`prompt()`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/prompt.htm)?

Comment: The only thing you can change about an alert is the text displayed within the alert. Use modal ("own") dialogs instead.

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes I am using a prompt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think generally you should try and minimize the use of alerts in your web application. They are very obtrusive and annoying. Generally people just update the DOM to display user information. An alert is for something more unique and important than somebody just mistyping their password.

EDIT:

As other people are pointing out, you should use modal dialogs instead to have behavior as you specify.

Comment: Although this is true, it is really more of a comment than an answer given that you didn't directly address the OP's two questions.

Comment: @nnnnnn True. I edited added my opinion on modal dialogs. I just think its important to note immediately that this is not a well accepted use of alert dialogs.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I agree, and was thinking about this when asking my question. But even if I should change my mind and implement my idea in another way I was curious about the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you can't do that since the way the alert is constructed and displayed is different in each browser (just look at mobile browsers). I think you'll safeguard your sanity longer if instead you use modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Being a blocking function, `alert()` is an abomination in itself, and owing to that would thwart the very thing you are trying to do.